# onregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/mutatingwebhookconfigurations: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Tags: kubernetes

The k8s cluster checks all the certificates without any problem, but the cluster suddenly has this problem, and it will be better later. This is very strange. May I ask where this problem may appear?

```
onregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/mutatingwebhookconfigurations: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Comment: Could you please provide a full error? Where exactly is the error seen? What type of cluster is it: managed or on-premise? How it was setup? What version of cluster? It's not enough details to even try to help you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.